# Using aws command using docker

Tags: docker, aws-cli

I am trying to upload a file to S3 using docker. I know how to use "aws" command, but not sure about the best way to use it within container.

```
# docker run --volume ~/.aws:/root/.aws -i --rm cgswong/aws:latest aws s3 cp mail.conf s3://mybucket/
```

I am getting an error:

> The user-provided path mail.conf does not exist.

Another problem is that I use putty and I have to duplcate a new terminal session after using this command because this command does not return to normal prompt.

How do I use the docker container the same way I use aws command line tool?

Comment: Try https://hub.docker.com/r/cgswong/aws/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is most probably that your `mail.conf` is in your current folder and not inside the container. So you should change your command to

```
docker run -v ~/.aws:/root/.aws -v "$PWD:/host/$PWD" -w "/host/$PWD" -i --rm cgswong/aws:latest aws s3 cp mail.conf s3://mybucket/
```

This will make sure that your current directory also is mounted in container and you start in the same folder inside the container also